# Find all real values of the parameter a for which the equation $x^4+2ax^3+x^2+2ax+1=0$ has

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Find all real values of the parameter a for which the equation $x^4+2ax^3+x^2+2ax+1=0$ has

1) exactly two distinct negative roots

2) at least two distinct negative roots

I tried to factorize it but didn't get any breakthrough.

Comment: The equation is reciprocal. Divide by $x^2$ and substitute $t=x+\frac 1x$ to get an equation in $t$ of second degree. Also note that (using the above or not) with $x$ the value $1/x$ is also a root. (So for (a) it is natural to look at $f(-1)$, $f$ being the associated polynomial function, it depends on the fixed parameter $a$.)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Example:_real_roots

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

This is a reciprocal equation, so set $y=x+\dfrac1x$. Dividing the equation by $x^2$, the equation can be rewritten as
$$x^2+2ax+1+\frac{2a}x+\frac1{x^2}=x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2a\Bigl(x+\frac1x\Bigl)+1=y^2+2ay-1=0.$$
Now, as the reduced discriminant is $\Delta'=a^2+1>0$, this equation in $x$ has two roots with opposite signs, whichs are also the signs of $x$ (if $x$ is real):
$$y=-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+1\mathstrut}.$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Here I also have a confusion regarding the 1st condition that equation should have exactly two distinct negative roots, does it mean equation can have 4 negative roots, but only 2 are distinct.

Comment: If you solve completely the given equation, you'll see that the two other roots are real. I've added that we speak of the sign of $x$ under the condition that it is real. But for one value of $y$, the equation in $x$: $x+\frac 1x=y$, has a negative discriminant.

Comment: I am asking generally that if in the question it is said that exactly two distinct negative roots,  does it mean equation can have multiple negative roots, but only 2 are distinct.

Comment: In this equation, only two roots are real. They're negative, and  for specific values of $a$, they're not distinct, i.e.you have a double root, if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Try $x^4+2ax^3+x^2+2ax+1=(x^2+bx+1)(x^2+cx+1)$.

Comment: Here I also have a confusion regarding the 1st condition that equation should have exactly two distinct negative roots, does it mean equation can have 4 negative roots, but only 2 are distinct.